# Number as array key?

Tags: php, arrays, key

Having problems getting the value 90000 from the array below. Shouldn't it just be below with php:

```
array["#SALDO"]["1220"]["#UB"]["-1"]
```

Or are numbers in keys not possible?

```
array (
[#SALDO] => Array
    (
        [1220] => Array
            (
                [#UB] => Array
                    (
                        [-1] => 90000.00
                        [0] => 10000.00
                    )

            )

        [1229] => Array
            (
                [#UB] => Array
                    (
                        [-1] => -20000
                        [0] => -18000
                    )

            )
)
```

Comment: @Devon It should work. "Integerish" strings are always converted to integers by PHP when dealing with array keys.

Comment: Yes, I just tested it @ShiraNai7, you are correct.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Which index is the specific problem?

Comment: Totally correct. Something else seems to be messing in my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  use numerical index when needed eg: `1220` instead of `"1220"` and `-1` instead of `"-1"`

```
 array["#SALDO"][1220]["#UB"][-1]
```